# Upgraded Drupal 7 - Cannot Install/Manage Modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

I have a multi site setup sharing the same codebase. I've followed http://drupal.org/node/570162 as closely as possible.

Where I get stuck at is my new site installation - I am unable to access nor install any new modules. If I attempt to access /admin/modules I receive a ACCESS DENIED error.

I am trying to migrate my fields by installing the new version of CCK - but I do not see a "Migrate Fields" option under "Structure" nor can I access it by direct url (/admin/structure/content_migrate).

Can I force Drupal to check my modules and recompile the list in some way? Or is some bigger problem at play here?

I am able to access other modules such as Blocks, Menus, Taxonomy. My modules all exist within /sites/all/modules with 755 permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this feels like one of those questions where you spend a lot of time and just wonder if it's a deficiency of knowledge about the system, docs, or human obliviousness.

After I upgraded I had to manually set myself to be able to administrate modules in /admin/people/permissions.

*voila*